# react-native-code-push app restart loop

Tags: android, react-native, code-push

- react-native-code-push version: 1.15.0-beta
- react-native version: 0.35.0
- iOS/Android/Windows version: Android 4.3
- Does this reproduce on a debug build or release build? Release
- Does this reproduce on a simulator, or only on a physical device? Device
- Repro steps and/or stack trace:

Using the old method of manually calling codepush sync. App downloads update and installs, however on restart it loops restarting until it has to be closed by holding down the home button and killing the app. I have implemented the part where you create an instance of ReactInstanceHolder, and use that in MainApplication.java. Haven't had an issue with this before, coming from 1.7.3-beta. Anyone else ran into this issue?

Comment: Hey , i saw on github that your issue is closed, can you please help: https://github.com/Microsoft/react-native-code-push/issues/872 ?